# Joomla Database values fetch in custom module

Tags: php, html, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have created a module in Joomla which will fetch the values from Joomla database table and show in a bootstrap HTML carousal. fetching part is working well but whenever I put the PHP code into Html code where I want those fields to display the carousel is not working. any help will be appreciated. below is my full page code (tmpl/dafault.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1.x"></script>
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select("*")
              ->from("tkps5_spotlightamsw_spotlight");
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $row = $db->loadObjectList();
            }
catch (exception $e) { echo $e; }
?>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="block-title1">xyz text</h2>
            <p class=" "><a class="button subbutton btn btn-border1" href="#">More info</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="block-title1">Spotlight</h2>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {  

                                    //Enable swiping...
                                    $(".carousel-inner").swipe( {
                                        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
                                        swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                                            $(this).parent().carousel('prev'); 
                                        },
                                        swipeRight: function() {
                                            $(this).parent().carousel('next'); 
                                        },
                                        //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                                        threshold:0
                                    });
                                });
                </script>

<?php foreach ($row as $row):  ?>
<?php
$fetured_spotlight = $row->featured_spotlight;
$name = $row->name;
$modified_date = $row->modified;
if($fetured_spotlight == 1 )
{
    echo "<div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' data-touch='true'> ";
    echo "  <div class='carousel-inner'>";
echo substr($modified_date,0 , 10);
echo "<div class='item '>";
echo "<img src='".$row->thumbnailimage."' alt='".$name."'>";
echo "<div class='carousel-caption1'>";
echo "<p><strong>".$name."</strong></p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
//echo $row->name;
echo "  <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='prev'>";
echo "                  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>";
echo "                  <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>";
echo "                </a>";
echo "                <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='next'>";
echo "                  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>";
echo "                  <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>";
echo "                </a>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
<?php endforeach;  ?>

                  <!-- Left and right controls 
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>-->

                <p class="align-right"><a class="button subbutton btn btn-border1" href="flame-spotlight">VIEW ALL</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: oof. that a lotta code. it might help to create a reduced test case

Comment: :-) ..  it's a full page code.. so helper will understand how and why im taking values from database like above.. problem is somewhere my in line - " echo "<div class='item '>"; " .. but not able to figure it out..

Comment: I suggest you to move all the logical and model instructions in an another class. For example you should move query in an helper file, call function in the main file of the module (modulename.php) and pass the value to the template through the loadTemplate function of joomla. In this way your page is more readable than now

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer where i was not assigning the "active" class to first slider image. so below is my working code .. just posting for loop rest of the code is same..

```
<?php foreach ($row as $key=>$row):  ?>
<?php
$fetured_spotlight = $row->featured_spotlight;
$name = $row->name;
if($fetured_spotlight == 1 )
{
?>

<div class='item <?php echo ($key == 0) ? "active" : ""; ?>'>
<?php
echo "<img src='".$row->thumbnailimage."' alt='".$name."'>";
echo "<div class='carousel-caption1'>";
echo "<p><strong>".$name."</strong></p>";
echo "</div>";

//echo $row->name;
     echo "<br />";
}
?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```